# QGIS 3.0 is showing a point's coordinates in the original spatial reference system instead of the project's spatial reference system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, nad83

I obtained GPS coordinates of a point to within a couple centimeter accuracy using RTK GPS in the NAD83 Spatial Reference System. This information is included in the QGIS layer file metadata, and the properties properly shows the spatial reference system as NAD83. However, I have my project spatial reference system set to WGS84 spatial reference system, and when I hover over the point, the coordinates displayed are the NAD83 coordinates instead of the WGS84 coordinates (which are different by about 1 meter in north america.I am using the UTM16N projection for both spatial reference systems, so the coordinates are displayed in meters. How can I get the map to display the transformed coordinates in the project's spatial reference system so that I can compare the coordinates of points with different spatial reference systems? ArcGIS displays the coordinates using the spatial reference system of the "view", and it seems misleading for QGIS not to be doing this.

Comment: QGIS relies on there being a transformation within the PROJ string for any non-WGS84 coordinate system. There may be none or 0,0,0 for NAD83 that you're using.

Comment: Thanks. Where would I find the PROJ string? When I select the layer properties, the following information is shown:<br/>Information from provider:<br/>
Encoding
UTF-8<br/>
Geometry
Point (Point25D)<br/>
CRS
EPSG:26916 - NAD83 / UTM zone 16N - Projected<br/>
Extent
362291.4670000000041910,4739836.7410000003874302 : 362559.9130000000004657,4739932.1639999998733401<br/>
Unit
meters<br/>
Feature count
66<br/>